# I am having a problem writing details for invoice into a text file. The Loop continues again and again

Tags: python, loops, file-handling, invoice

I am writing an invoice for a store in .txt file format and have multiple .py files to handle the volume of main file. Anyway, When the program asks user to input the laptop id, I inputted the id value but the loop continues for the id value and doesn't proceed to the billing section. The program asks id again and again.

Following is the code written. The loop continues again and again asking id of the laptop.

In read.py:

```
def openFile():
    laptopDetailsDictionary = {}
    file = open("laptopDetails.txt", "r")
    laptopId = 1
    for line in file:
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        laptopDetailsDictionary[laptopId] = line.split(",")
        laptopId += 1
    return laptopDetailsDictionary


def readFromTextFile():
    a = 1
    file = open("laptopDetails.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        print(a, "\t "+line.replace(",", "\t\t"))
        a += 1
    file.close()


def inputField():
    name = input("Please provide us your name:")
    phone = (input("Please provide us your phone number:"))
    return name, phone
```

In operations.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from read import readFromTextFile, openFile, input_name, input_phone

laptopDetailsDictionary = {}
# buy


def buy():
    laptopDetailsDictionary = openFile()

    print("Let's shop.")
    print("\n")
    print("We will need your name and contact number for the invoice.")
    print("\n")

    '''name = input("Please provide us your name:")
    phone = (input("Please provide us your phone number:"))'''
    print("\n")
    print("-"*130)

    print("S.N \t Name \t\t\t Brand \t\t\t Quantity \t Price \t\t Processor \t\t Graphic Card")
    print("-"*130)
    readFromTextFile()
    print("\n")

    validLaptopId = int(
        input("Please Provide the ID of the laptop you want to buy:"))
    print("\n")
    # validate id
    while validLaptopId <= 0 or validLaptopId > len(laptopDetailsDictionary):
        print("Please provide a valid laptop id!!!")
        print("\n")
        validLaptopId = int(
            input("Please provide the ID of the laptop you want to buy::"))

# laptop's quantity

    laptopQuantity = int(
        input("Please provide the number of quantity of laptop::"))
    print("\n")
# Update the text file

    laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][3] = int(
        laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][3]) + int(laptopQuantity)

    nameOfProduct = laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][0]
    totalQuantity = laptopQuantity
    unitPrice = (laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][2])
    price = laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][2].replace("$", '')
    totalPrice = int(price) * int(totalQuantity)
    vatAmount = 0.13 * totalPrice
    grossAmount = totalPrice + vatAmount
    dateandtime = datetime.now()
    # dateandtime = datetime.datetime.now()
    brandName = laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][1]
    bill_Number = datetime.now()
    customersDictionary = []
    customersDictionary.append(
        [nameOfProduct, totalQuantity, unitPrice, price, totalPrice, vatAmount, grossAmount])

    print("\n")
    print("Bit & Byte Store", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" " Date: ",
          dateandtime.strftime("%d" " " "%b"",""%Y"))
    print("London,England", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" "   " "Time:",
          dateandtime.strftime("%I" ":" "%M" "%p"))
    print("bitandbyte@gmail.com")
    print("073599487")

    print("\n")
    print("Bill Number:" + str(dateandtime.strftime("%f")))

    print("-"*98)
    print("S.N", "\t\t", "Product's Name", "\t", "Brand",
          "\t\t  ", "Quantity", "\t\t", "Amount")
    print("-"*98)
    print(" 1 ", "\t\t" + str(nameOfProduct), "\t\t" + str(brandName),
          "\t""\t" + str(totalQuantity) + "\t" + str(unitPrice))
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("-"*98)
    print("Net Amount:", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "$" + str(totalPrice))
    print("Vat Amount:", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "$" + str(vatAmount))
    print("-"*98)
    print("Gross Amount:", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "$" + str(grossAmount))
    print("-"*98)
    print("\n")
    print("Terms & Conditions" "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "Bank Details")
    print("Payment is due within 15 days." "\t\t\t\t\t" "    " "Bank of United Kingdom")
    print("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "Account Number:0530 1178 7908")
    print("\n")

    print("\t\t\t\t""  ", "Thank You for your order.")
    print("\n")


# sell


def sell():

    laptopDetailsDictionary = openFile()
    print("Let's shop.")
    print("\n")
    print("We will need your name and contact number for the invoice.")
    print("\n")

    # name = input("Please provide us your name:")
    # phone = (input("Please provide us your phone number:"))
    print("\n")
    print("-"*130)
    print("S.N \t Name \t\t\t Brand \t\t\t Quantity \t Price \t\t Processor \t\t Graphic Card")
    print("-"*130)

    readFromTextFile()

    # valid id
    print("\n")

    validLaptopId = int(
        input("Please Provide the ID of the laptop you want to buy:"))
    print("\n")
    while validLaptopId <= 0 or validLaptopId > len(laptopDetailsDictionary):
        print("Pleaase provide a valid laptop id!!!")
        print("\n")
        validLaptopId = int(
            input("Please provide the ID of the laptop you want to buy::"))

    laptopQuantity = int(input("Please provide the number of quantity of ::"))
    print("\n")
    requiredQuantity = laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][3]

    while laptopQuantity <= 0 or laptopQuantity > int(requiredQuantity):
        print("Dear" + str(input_name()) +
              "the quantity you are looking for is not available instock!!!")
        print("\n")
        laptopQuantity = int(
            input("Please provide the number of quantity of ::"))
    print("\n")

    # Update the text file

    laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][3] = int(
        laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][3]) - int(laptopQuantity)

    # getting user purchased items

    nameOfProduct = laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][0]
    totalQuantity = laptopQuantity
    unitPrice = laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][2]
    price = laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][2].replace("$", '')
    totalPrice = int(price) * int(totalQuantity)
    brandName = laptopDetailsDictionary[validLaptopId][1]
    customersDictionary = []
    dateandtime = datetime.now()
    customersDictionary.append(
        [nameOfProduct, totalQuantity, unitPrice, price, totalPrice])

    shipping = (input("Do you want your laptop to be shipped?(y/n):"))

    if shipping == "y".lower():
        print("\n")

        print("Shipping charge varies inside and outside capital.")
        print("\n")

        shippingLocation = (
            input("Where do want your product to be delivered??(i/o:)"))

        if shippingLocation == "i".lower():
            shippingCharge = 200
        elif shippingLocation == "o".lower():
            shippingCharge = 400
        print("\n")

        location = input(
            "Please provide us your full address for the delivery:")

    else:
        print("Thank You for your order.")
        shippingCharge = 0
        location = None

    print("\n")
    print("Bit & Byte Store" "\t\t\t""   " + "Bill To"  "\t\t\t\t" "Date: " +
          str(dateandtime.strftime("%d" " " "%b"",""%Y")))
    print("London,England" + "\t\t\t\t" + "Name:" + str(input_name()) + "\t\t\t\t " + "Time: " +
          str(dateandtime.strftime("%I" ":" "%M" "%p")))
    print("bitandbyte@gmail.com" + "\t\t\t" + "Location:" + str(location))
    print("073599487" + "\t\t\t\t" + "Contact:" + str(input_phone))

    print("\n")
    print("Bill Number:" + str(dateandtime.strftime("%f")))

    print("-"*98)
    print("S.N" + "\t\t" + "Product's Name" + "\t" + "Brand" +
          "\t\t" + "Quantity" + "\t\t" + "Amount")
    print("-"*98)
    print(" 1 ", "\t\t" + str(nameOfProduct) + "\t\t" + str(brandName) +
          "\t\t" + str(totalQuantity) + "\t" + str(unitPrice))
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("-"*98)
    print("Net Amount:" + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "$" + str(totalPrice))
    print("Shipping Charge:" + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "$" + str(shippingCharge))
    print("-"*98)
    print("Gross Amount:" + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",
          "$" + (str(totalPrice)+str(shippingCharge)))
    print("-"*98)
    print("\n")
    print("Terms & Conditions" "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "Bank Details")
    print("Payment is due within 15 days." "\t\t\t\t\t" "    " "Bank of United Kingdom")
    print("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "Account Number:0530 1178 7908")
    print("\n")

    print("\t\t\t\t""  " + "Thank You for your order.")
    print("\n")
```

In write.py:

```
import operations
import read
from datetime import datetime
laptopDetailsDictionary = {}


def writeTextFile():
    file = open("laptop.txt", "w")

    for values in laptopDetailsDictionary.values():
        file.write(str(values[0]) + "," + str(values[1]) + "," + str(values[2]) +
                   "," + str(values[3]) + "," + str(values[4]) + "," + str(values[5]))
        file.write("\n")
    file.close()


def invoiceSell(name, phone, nameOfProduct, totalQuantity, unitPrice,  totalPrice, brandName, shippingCharge):
    dateandtime = datetime.now()

    with open(str(name) + str(phone) + ".txt ", 'w') as sell:

        sell.write("\n")
        sell.write("Bit & Byte Store" + "\t\t\t""   " + "Bill To" + "\t\t\t\t")
        sell.write(str(dateandtime.now()))
        sell.write("bitandbyte@gmail.com", "\t\t\t",
                   "Location:", operations.location)
        sell.write("073599487", "\t\t\t\t", "Contact:", phone)

        sell.write("\n")
        sell.write("Bill Number:" + dateandtime.strftime("%f"))

        sell.write("-"*98)
        sell.write("S.N", "\t\t", "Product's Name", "\t", "Brand",
                   "\t\t",  "Quantity", "\t\t", "Amount")
        sell.write("-"*98)
        sell.write(" 1 ", "\t\t", nameOfProduct, "\t\t", brandName,
                   "\t\t", totalQuantity, "\t", unitPrice)
        sell.write("\n")
        sell.write("\n")
        sell.write("-"*98)
        sell.write("Net Amount:", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",
                   "$", totalPrice)
        sell.write("Shipping Charge:", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",
                   "$", shippingCharge)
        sell.write("-"*98)
        sell.write("Gross Amount:", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",
                   "$", (totalPrice+shippingCharge))
        sell.write("-"*98)
        sell.write("\n")
        sell.write("Terms & Conditions" "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "Bank Details")
        
        #Details

        sell.write("\t\t\t\t""  ", "Thank You for your order.")
        sell.write("\n")

        for i in operations.customersDictionary:
            operations.customersDictionary(
                str(i[0])+str(i[1]) + str(i[2])+str(i[3])+str(i[4]))


writeTextFile()
```

In main.py:

```
import write
import operations


def welcome():
    print("\n")
    print("\t\t", " " "*"*50)
    print("\t \t \t \t \t \t    Welcome to  Store Name ")
    print("\n")

    print("\t\t", " " "*"*50)
    print("\t '\t \t \t \t \t \t City, Country")
    print("\n")

    print("\t\t", " " "*"*50)
    print("\n")


def userOptions():

    continueLoop = True
    while continueLoop == True:
        print("\t \t 1.  Press 1 to buy from manufacturer.")
        print("\t \t 2.  Press 2 to sell to customers.")
        print("\t \t 3.  Press 3 to exit from system.")
        print("\n")

        options = True
        while options == True:
            try:
                optionsInput = int(input("\tEnter from option:"))
                print("\n")

                options = False
            except:
                print("Please insert numeric values only!")

        if optionsInput == 1:
            operations.buy()

        elif optionsInput == 2:
            name, phone = operations.sell()
            write.invoiceSell(name, phone)

        elif optionsInput == 3:
            continueLoop = False

        else:
            print("Please check option and continue")


welcome()
userOptions()
```